# If-else statement in R coding did not work

Tags: r, if-statement

I did coding in R as below,

```
  data1<-c(25,35,60,79,50)
  data2<-c(100,150,170,200,1000)
  
  g1=sort(data1)
  g2=sort(data2)
  
  ybar1<-mean(g1)
  ybar2<-mean(g2)
  
  #BIWEIGHT
  
  med1=median(g1)
  med2=median(g2)
  
  mad1=1.4826*(median(abs(g1-med1)))
  mad2=1.4826*(median(abs(g2-med2)))

  u1=(g1-med1)/(9*mad1)
  u2=(g2-med2)/(9*mad2)
  
  #cat("\nu1:",u1)
  u=rbind(u1,u2)
  print(u)
  
  abs=abs(u)
  print(abs)
  
    for(j in abs){
      if(j < 1){
        num1 = ((g1-med1)^2)*((1-(u1^2))^4)
        den1 = ((1-(u1^2))*(1-5*(u1^2)))
        
        num2 = ((g2-med2)^2)*((1-(u2^2))^4)
        den2 = ((1-(u2^2))*(1-5*(u2^2)))
      }
    }
  
  cat("\num2:",num2)
```

but when i calculate manually, for data1, every value u1 is less than 1, thus the coding is right with my manual calculation, but for data2, it include value of u2 that is more than 1. can anyone help me figure out why it happen and how to fix it?
thankyou in advance.

Comment: You are overwriting `num2` in every cycle of the `for` loop, so the value of `num2` you are printing is for the final number in `abs`

Comment: how should i correct it?

Comment: Declare your variables as empty vectors by doing `num1 <- den1 <- num2 <- den2 <- c()` before the loop, and during the loop do `num1 = c(num1, (((g1-med1)^2)*((1-(u1^2))^4))` and so on for each of the 4 variables (i.e. concatenate the result of the loop onto the vectors each cycle)

Comment: for the if part, it still read the value of `abs` that is more than 1 even though the condition of `if` is less than 1  :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to me that within the `if` condition (and therefore also within the `for` loop), you always take the entire vectors (`g1`, `g2`, `u1`, `u2`). You do not tell R *to only use those values* in g1 and g2 for which j<1. Instead you use the entire vector *as many times as there are values* in `abs` that are <1.

Furthermore, you combine `u1` and `u2` as a 2-row matrix, but leave g1 and g2 separate. This is confusing and gets you more problems. I suggest you do separate loops for the two vectors.

You can do that as follows:

```
idx1 <- which(abs(u1) < 1) #Gives you the indexes/positions in vector u1, where abs(u1)<1 is TRUE
idx2 <- which(abs(u2) < 1) #same for u2

for(i in idx1){
               num1[i] = ((g1[i]-med1)^2)*((1-(u1[i]^2))^4)
               den1[i] = ((1-(u1[i]^2))*(1-5*(u1[i]^2)))
               }
for(j in idx2){
               num2[j] = ((g2[j]-med2)^2)*((1-(u2[j]^2))^4)
               den2[j] = ((1-(u2[j]^2))*(1-5*(u2[j]^2)))
               }
```

This way, `num1` and `den1` have 5 elements because all absolute values of u1 are <1.
In contrast, `num2` and `den2` have 4 elements, because the last value of u2 is ca. 2.07.

Hopefully, this helps you.

EDIT: Forgot to add the indices (`[i] and [j]`) to `num1`/`2` and `den1`/`2`.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, i've been stuck with the same thing for the past week. Thank you again :))